# Turning a Standard XTS Object Into a Seasonal Plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, xts

The package fpp2 has a wonderful function ggseaonplot(). I would like to make use of it by turning my xts object into a matrix where "Years" are the row names and the 12 months are the columns names.

```
#here is the data. This is stock data from yahoo finance
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("SPY")
adjusted = Ad(SPY)
head(adjusted)
```

[image]

```
#here is an example of what I would like the data to look like using the  
AirPassengers matrix.
dput(AirPassengers)
structure(c(112, 118, 132, 129, 121, 135, 148, 148, 136, 119, 
104, 118, 115, 126, 141, 135, 125, 149, 170, 170, 158, 133, 114, 
140, 145, 150, 178, 163, 172, 178, 199, 199, 184, 162, 146, 166, 
171, 180, 193, 181, 183, 218, 230, 242, 209, 191, 172, 194, 196, 
196, 236, 235, 229, 243, 264, 272, 237, 211, 180, 201, 204, 188, 
235, 227, 234, 264, 302, 293, 259, 229, 203, 229, 242, 233, 267, 
269, 270, 315, 364, 347, 312, 274, 237, 278, 284, 277, 317, 313, 
318, 374, 413, 405, 355, 306, 271, 306, 315, 301, 356, 348, 355, 
422, 465, 467, 404, 347, 305, 336, 340, 318, 362, 348, 363, 435, 
491, 505, 404, 359, 310, 337, 360, 342, 406, 396, 420, 472, 548, 
559, 463, 407, 362, 405, 417, 391, 419, 461, 472, 535, 622, 606, 
508, 461, 390, 432), .Tsp = c(1949, 1960.91666666667, 12), class = "ts")
```

[image]

Here is what the final project should look similar to.

```
library(fpp2)
ggseasonplot(AirPassengers)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class(adjusted) 
#[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

`adjusted` is of type `xts` but `ggseasonplot` needs object of type `ts`.

Here is an alternative with `ggplot2` though

**Prepare the data**

```
library(zoo)
df <- data.frame(date = index(adjusted),value = coredata(adjusted),row.names = NULL)
df$month <- factor(format(df$date, "%b"), levels = month.abb)
df$year <- format(df$date, "%Y")
```

**Plot the data**

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) +
   aes(month, SPY.Adjusted, group = year, color = year) + 
   geom_line()
```

[image]